# Listing scratch org in different PC

Tags: scratch-org

Yesterday In my home computer I created a devhub account. Using the account i created a scratch org called MgmtScratch. I did all my work in that scratch org. I then went to my office and executed **sfdx force:auth:web:login** to connect my devhub account. I connected it successfully and executed **sfdx force:org:list --all** but could not see my scratch org(MgmtScratch).

Edit: I can see the scratch org in my devhub(browser) but I cannot see on terminal.
[image]

Can any one help me on this??

Comment: How long was it between these? I assume information on scratch orgs is maintained in the dev hub, but scratch orgs are called such because they're thrown away after some period of time.

Comment: 1 day, I can see my active scratch org in devhub(browser) but not on terminal. 
I even executed  the command sfdx force:org:open -u MgmtScratch but got an error.
ERROR:  No org configuration found for name MgmtScratch .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you will not be able to see your scratch org in different system.

To see the scratch org on terminal of a different system you need to have json file related to your scratch org.

This json file in windows is present in the location c:/users/username/.sfdx. The .sfdx folder which is a hidden folder by default have all the scratch org configuration.

So, you will have to send a copy of json file and send to your work mail.

To identify the org, just open your devhub account and look at the id of it. You will have a json file in .sfdx folder with name as the id.
This json file contains accessToken, refreshToken e.t.c so creating your custom json file in .sfdx folder will be futile.

Comment: I have a slightly [different problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/332682/scratch-org-create-succeeded-after-timeout-now-how-do-i-register-org-in-my-vscod) - any ideas?